# Laravel Notifications Base Table not found

Tags: mysql, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.5, pusher

I am working on a Laravel project. I ran these commands and successfully created notifications table.

```
php artisan notifications:table
php artisan migrate
```

All of the things were going perfectly. Later on I created a Model name "NotificationsForAdmin" with migration named "notifications_for_admin", then later on I drooped this table. Now when I am trying to generate some notifications then it is showing me this error, I dont know whats going on I have notifications table in database that is needed for laravel notifications with perfect schema. the error is :

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'followup.notification_for_admins' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `notification_for_admins` where `notification_for_admins`.`user_id` = 2 and `notification_for_admins`.`user_id` is not null)
```

My notifications is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Events\NewEmailReceivedEvent;
use Auth;

    class NewEmailReceived extends Notification
    {
        use Queueable;

        public $sender_id, $receiver_id, $sender_name, $receiver_name, $sender_type, $receiver_type, $type, $recipient, $from_email, $subject, $message, $image, $receiver_image, $attachments, $sizesOfAttachments, $originalFileNames, $thread_id, $id_of_email;

        /**
         * Create a new notification instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct($sender_id, $receiver_id, $sender_name, $receiver_name, $sender_type, $receiver_type, $type, $recipient, $from_email, $subject, $message, $image, $receiver_image, $attachments, $sizesOfAttachments, $originalFileNames, $thread_id, $id_of_email)
        {
            $this->sender_id = $sender_id;
            $this->receiver_id = $receiver_id;
            $this->sender_name = $sender_name;
            $this->receiver_name = $receiver_name;
            $this->sender_type = $sender_type;
            $this->receiver_type = $receiver_type;
            $this->type = $type;
            $this->recipient = $recipient;
            $this->from_email = $from_email;
            $this->subject = $subject;
            $this->message = $message;
            $this->image = $image;
            $this->receiver_image = $receiver_image;
            $this->attachments = $attachments;
            $this->sizesOfAttachments = $sizesOfAttachments;
            $this->originalFileNames = $originalFileNames;
            $this->thread_id = $thread_id;
            $this->id_of_email = $id_of_email;
        }

        /**
         * Get the notification's delivery channels.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return array
         */
        public function via($notifiable)
        {
            $notifications = Auth::user()->notifications;
            if ($notifications[7]->shown == 1) {
                return ['mail', 'database'];
            }
            else{
                return ['database'];
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the array representation of the notification.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return array
         */
        public function toDatabase($notifiable)
        {
            return [
                'sender_id' => $this->sender_id,
                'receiver_id' => $this->receiver_id,
                'sender_name' => $this->sender_name,
                'receiver_name' => $this->receiver_name,
                'sender_type' => $this->sender_type,
                'receiver_type' => $this->receiver_type,
                'type' => $this->type,
                'recipient' => $this->recipient,
                'from_email' => $this->from_email,
                'subject' => $this->subject,
                'message' => $this->message,
                'image' => $this->image,
                'receiver_image' => $this->receiver_image,
                'attachments' => $this->attachments,
                'sizesOfAttachments' => $this->sizesOfAttachments,
                'originalFileNames' => $this->originalFileNames,
                'thread_id' => $this->thread_id,
                'id_of_email' => $this->id_of_email,
            ];
            event(new NewEmailReceivedEvent($NewEmailReceivedRequest));
            return $NewEmailReceivedRequest;
        }

        /**
         * Get the mail representation of the notification.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
         */
        public function toMail($notifiable)
        {
            return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject("New email from ".$this->sender_type)
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->markdown('mails.NewEmailReceived' , ['recipient_name' => $this->receiver_name , 'subject' => $this->subject , 'mailMessage' => str_limit($this->message, 50) , 'avatar' => $this->image]);
        }


        /**
         * Get the array representation of the notification.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $notifiable
         * @return array
         */
        public function toArray($notifiable)
        {
            return [
                //
            ];
        }
    }
```

I shall be very thankfull if someone could help me on this.

Comment: what is your table name in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `notifications` relation on your `User` object still references `NotificationsForAdmin`.

If you do not specify the table for a model, the table is automatically generated as a snake_case string of the model name. In the case of `NotificationsForAdmin` this becomes `notification_for_admins`.

Add the public property `$table` to your `NotificationsForAdmin` with the name of the table where your notifications are stored as the value. This should fix your problem.